# Save new object to table (StorIO)

Tags: android, storio

I want save all objects ReportDB as new row in DB

```
 App.get(context)
    .getStorIO()
    .put()
    .object(new ReportDB(keyStore.getKeyCategoryId(), keyStore.getKeyShelfId()))
    .prepare()
    .asRxObservable().subscribe(putResult -> ZLog.d("insertedId = "+putResult.insertedId()),
            throwable -> ZLog.d("throwable = ",throwable));
```

ReportDB is

```
@StorIOSQLiteColumn(name = ReportTable.COLUMN_ID,key = true)
long id;

@StorIOSQLiteColumn(name = ReportTable.CATEGORY_ID_I)
long categoryId;

@StorIOSQLiteColumn(name = ReportTable.SHELF_ID_I)
long shelfId;

@StorIOSQLiteColumn(name = ReportTable.LATITUDE_R)
double latitude;

@StorIOSQLiteColumn(name = ReportTable.LONGITUDE_R)
double longitude;

public ReportDB(long categoryId, long shelfId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.shelfId = shelfId;
}
```

But now, after run code twice, I have only one row and logs

```
 insertedId = 0
 insertedId = null
```

How auto increment id ?

Answer (score 1):

StorIO does not manage tables schema for you, it just binds to existing db and works with it, so you have 2 ways to achieve autoincrement column:

1. Create column as `INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`
2. Increment counter yourself in the `PutResolver` of your entity (don't forget about wrapping this code into transaction!)

I'd suggest to use 1st option because it'll work faster and you don't have to write any code for that -> harder to make a mistake :)